# Create UIImageView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm trying to add an Image to my view. I tried the following code:

```
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tag40pixelsborder.png"]];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 30, 30);
//    imgView.bounds = CGRectMake(300, 300, 32, 32);
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];


    NSLog(@"frame x %f", imgView.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"frame y %f", imgView.frame.origin.y);
```

But the picture doesn't appear on screen, and NSLog return 30.00 for "x" and 0.00 for "y" If I uncomment the bounds line and I remove the frame line, I get 80.00 for "x" and 80.00 for "y".

I am using autolayout, but the exact same code works on another view! What's wrong?

Comment: what are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: That code works for me, Ve you added image to xcode check the spelling of image

Comment: I copied-paste the name of the image, I'm sure it's the good one.

Comment: That's the thing. The image is 160x160, but I want to resize it. There's a typo, it should be 32x32 so I downsize it at a 5 to 1 ratio.

Comment: If you insist on using autoLayout, how about adding the ImageView inside IB but then setting image at runtime through the code?

Comment: Because there might be multiple images at different positions on the screen, depending on what the user does.

Comment: In your position, I would not use autolayout at all. If you still want to use itI suggest adding an additional UIView with proper autolayout constraints on IB, and then addding all UIImageViews on to that UIView at runtime instead of vc's own view

Comment: I just desactivated Autolayout. The code still doesn't work. It returns 32.00 for "x" and 0.00 for "y". In ViewDidAppear and ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use auto layout to do this then you should do something along these lines.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tag40pixelsborder.png"]];
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[imgView sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Then you will want to set the auto layout constraints what i see you have is x = 200 y = 200

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint 
                        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(200)-[imgView]"
                        options:0
                        metrics:nil
                        views:@{ @"imgView" : imgView }];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint 
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(200)-[imgView]"
               options:0
               metrics:nil
               views:@{ @"imgView" : imgView }]; 
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

The above will make the image view 200 from the top and 200 from the left of the parent view i.e. self.view in this case.

If you wanted to add the heights you could remove the [imgView sizeToFit] and just add heights to the width and height constraints i.e. |-(200)-[imgView(width)] and same for the height in the one marked with the V:.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get "No known class method for selector 'constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views' " from Xcode. Did I forget to import something?

Comment: However the image now shows up (with your first 5 lines of code), but it in in original resolution (160x160) and whenever I want to change the frame/bounds, it disappears.

Comment: should have been constraintsWithVisualFormat not constraintWithVisualFormat try that Xcode should not cause an issue now

Comment: Error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
V:|-(200)-[imgView]

Comment: I think it's trying to tell me I'm trying to load another view. I just want to add my UIImageView where I need it!

Comment: did you add imgView to the self.view you must do that first before setting the constraints otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Oops, my bad. It now "works", the image shows on the screen and I can get it to change position by playing with the number, but I don't understand how it works (I get stack errors.). How would you do to make it appear at 100,400 ? Also, it's still in 160x160, how to resize it in 32x32?

Comment: for resizing you would do [imgView(32)] that will give the width or height depending on the V: which is vertical and the one without which is horizontal. Also for 100 , 400 put the V:|-(400)-[imgView] and for the 100 do |-(100)-[imgView]

Comment: Thanks! After much trouble (it's not so simple, isn't it), the solution is yours. For others, to resize, just add another constraint and follow the instructions in the last comment.

Comment: Anthony glad it is working for you now, yeah the Visual aspect of autolayout will take a little getting used too but once you know what each piece does it is a powerful tool and can save you a lot code than using the non visual auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `autolayout` like you said you should avoid to add subviews from code! If you want to do this you should programmatically add `constrains` also. Your code is fine but autolayout are messing with it. If you want dirty solution you should add this ImageView after everything is loaded (in `viewDidAppear:` method for example).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it didn't work, even in ViewDidAppear. What kind of constrains do I need to make it work? I don't think it's normal that I get these kind of NSLog